# What is the difference between the magnetic field above the conducting wire and below ? Why magnetic changes it's direction when kept above and below?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What is the difference between the magnetic field above the conducting wire and below it? I ask it with reference to Oersted's experiment. I mean it is always stated the direction in which the compass needle deflects to above and below the wire when current is flowing in the same direction but why does it flip by $180^{\circ}$ (?) is given nowhere. So

- Why does it change its direction above and below the wire?
- What is the reason ?

Comment: Haven't you been introduced to magnetostatics ?

Comment: see; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oersted%27s_law#Direction_of_the_magnetic_field  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_and_electric_currents

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it change its direction above and below the wire?
>
> What is the reason ?

First of all, it is an experimental result. The postulated existence of a magnetic field around a conductor, and how it changes in direction and intensity according to angle and distance, is a consequence of that result.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of a wire is circular around the wire, so it changes direction continually if you go around the wire.